# Populating secondary dropdown from main dropdown through JS

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown which must populate several other dropdowns depending on the option selected. I found a way how to do this using hidden fields. I created a hidden field for every sub dropdown with all its options. Then from my JS function, I check which selectedIndex is selected and then give the value of its respective hidden field.

This way works great, however, I am setting the value of the sub dropdown using the variable ID FROM the Js function. This reduces flexibility.

Does anybody know any other way how to pass all the parameters from the HTML?

Best method would be that all dropdowns are there but are not displayed. Upon change of the main dropdown, the respective sub drop down ONLY is shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think your "best method" suggestion is in fact the best method, at least as long as the volume of data (selections) involved isn't too great.  Just have each option in the "main" select have a class or attribute value that indicates which secondary select should be shown.

Comment: Also, the topic of controlling one dropdown from another is extremely well-covered with older stackoverflow questions. You can probably find a lot of suggestions and a lot of variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do just what you want, have all the dropdowns hidden except the correct one.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function changedropdown(index) {
  dropdowns['dropdown1'].style.display='none';
  dropdowns['dropdown2'].style.display='none';
  dropdowns['dropdown3'].style.display='none';
  dropdowns['dropdown4'].style.display='none';
  dropdowns[index].style.display='inline';
}
</script> 

<form name='dropdowns'> 
  <select onchange='changedropdown(options[selectedIndex].value)'> 
    <option selected value='dropdown1'>1</option> 
    <option value='dropdown2'>2</option> 
    <option value='dropdown3'>3</option> 
    <option value='dropdown4'>4</option> 
  </select> 

  <select name='dropdown1'> 
    <option selected value=1>dropdown1</option> 
  </select> 
  <select style='display:none' name='dropdown2'> 
    <option selected value=1>dropdown2</option> 
  </select> 
  <select style='display:none' name='dropdown3'> 
    <option selected value=1>dropdown3</option> 
  </select> 
  <select style='display:none' name='dropdown4'> 
    <option selected value=1>dropdown4</option> 
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue, the hidden values are not being returned in your post?  To get around this issue I run a routine on submit that grabs all the hidden values and puts them into non hidden inputs of type hidden.

So...assuming you use jquery that would be something along the lines of

```
<div id='hiddenValues'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function onSubmit() {
        var hiddenValue = $('$yourHiddenSelectBox').val();
        $('#hiddenValues').append("<input type='hidden' name='someId' value='" + hiddenValue + "'>";
    }
 </script>
```